# Получение названия тега по хешу коммита

Tags: git

Есть хеш, например: 234nk3l254b36k3ol563;
Команда `git show 234nk3l254b36k3ol563` выдаёт результат:

```
commit 234nk3l254b36k3ol563 (tag: 1.1.5, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: ...
Author: ...
Date: ...
    Merge branch 'release/1.1.5'
```

какую git команду нужно ввести, чтобы получить только название тега "1.1.5" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так?

```sh
git tag --points-at 234nk3l254b36k3ol563
```

Помните, что на один коммит может ссылаться несколько меток.